# angular4: map enum from service

Tags: json, angular, mapping

My angular 4 angular sends an object to a server and everything is working except the mapping of an enum.

My server sends me

```
{
"paymentState":"OUTSTANDING"
}
```

and to map this my objects has this enum:

```
export enum PaymentState {
    NONE,
    OUTSTANDING,
    SETTLED
}
```

Problem 1: The PaymentState on my object that I mapped from server is not the string literal but 1 for example.

Second thing is that I send numbers instead of string literals.
E.g. I set

```
myReservation.paymentState = PaymentState.SETTLED;
```

And my json object is

{
"paymentState": 2
}

Currently my hhtpClient map method looks like this

```
.map(response => response);
```

What Do I need to adjust?

Comment: `export type PaymentState = 'NONE' | 'OUTSTANDING' | 'SETTLED';`? Or use a string enum: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html?

Comment: no - this doesn't work in angular 4

Comment: What doesn't work? How doesn't it work?

Comment: 'PaymentState' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: What is "here". Which code causes that error to happen?

Comment: e.g. this.reservation.paymentState === PaymentState.SETTLED;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158803/discussion-between-netshark1000-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: You need to change that line of code to this.reservation.paymentState === 'SETTLED'. Unless you're using my second suggestion.